# How can you prevent subbibliography appearing on the ToC in Memoir class?

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, memoir

I have created sub-bibliographies using the keyword methods to distinguish between primary and secondary sources. This works fine but the only thing is that in the table of contents it lists all the sub-bibliographies as separate entries. For example;

> Bibliography.....45
>
> Sub-Biblio1......45
>
> Sub-Biblio1......49

I wish to just have Bibliography in the ToC and not the sub ones so I’m assuming (maybe wrongly) that `\nobibintoc' isn't the solution as it removes everything.

I have looked at some questions here but can't seem to find a solution.

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, bookpages=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
address = {Anytown},
booktitle = {Example book},
pages = {5},
title = {{Any book you want}},
year = {2000}
}
@article{EPaper12/12/2000,
address = {anytown},
journal = {Example Newpaper},
date = {2000-12-12},
month = {12.12.},
pages = {5},
keywords = {primary},
title = {{Another Title you want}},
year = {1915}
}


\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname} % if you’re using biblatex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\lipsum[1]\footcite{book1}
\lipsum[1]\footcite{EPaper12/12/2000}


\printbibheading
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Primary Sources}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Secondary Sources}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `\nobibintoc` after `\printbibheading` but before the `\printbibliography` commands:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text
\usepackage[notes, backend=biber, bookpages=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{book1,
address = {Anytown},
booktitle = {Example book},
pages = {5},
title = {{Any book you want}},
year = {2000}
}
@article{EPaper12/12/2000,
address = {anytown},
journal = {Example Newpaper},
date = {2000-12-12},
month = {12.12.},
pages = {5},
keywords = {primary},
title = {{Another Title you want}},
year = {1915}
}


\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{\jobname} % if you’re using biblatex
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\lipsum[1]\footcite{book1}
\lipsum[1]\footcite{EPaper12/12/2000}


\printbibheading
\nobibintoc
\printbibliography[keyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Primary Sources}]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=primary,heading=subbibliography,%
title={Secondary Sources}]

\end{document}
```

The first page of the output, showing the desired ToC:

[image]

Comment: Tempted fate by saying I didn't think \nobibintoc was the solution! I had tried it, but before \printbibheading rather than after. +1 and an accept.